# And again: submit is not a function

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following code for my form:

```
<form name="myform" id='form' class="form" method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8' action="action.php">


<div>
<input type='submit' id="sendbtn" value='Hello' class="loginbutton">
</div>

</form>
```

In my Javascript I have a form checker that - if the check succeeds - should submit the form. However - that doesn't work.

The javascript is:

```
const sendit = document.getElementById("sendbtn");

function showSuccess(input){
    const formControl = input.parentElement;
    formControl.className = 'form-control success';
    sendit.submit();
}
```

That code throws the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: sendit.submit is not a function
```

Because I already learned that names or ids called "submit" override the submit-function, I checked my code for the usage of "submit". But there's simply no other usage in the php or the javascript except an addEventListener for the type "submit".

What could be the problem here?

Comment: [`submit` is a method of `<form>`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit), not of `<input>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pointing the `input`, not the `form`, which is the element who will submit the form.

```
const sendit = document.getElementById("form");
```

Your function that submits the form, has to point to the form id `form`. You are pointing a button, which doesn't have the submit event.

Comment: How do I change that? By something like form.sendit.submit() ? That doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Updated the answer, basically you have to make the getElementById point the form id

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hints.

I now added another function:

```
function submitForm(form) {
    sendit.submit();
}
```

And I call it by submitForm(); from within the function "showSuccess". But that throws the same error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: sendit.submit is not a function
```

I should clearify that I am just starting with javascript. My problem seems stupid to you, but is still complex for me.

Comment: You're still trying to call `submit` on the *button*. You need to call `submit` on the *form*. Where you do `document.getElementById("sendbtn")`, don't get the *button* by id, get the *form*.

Comment: If it's not an answer, don't answer it, edit your initial post with the changes you have tried

Comment: It works! By this problem I got a better understanding of how javascript works on forms. Thank you!